# Can I compile a windows only software for ubuntu

Tags: windows, wine, compiling

I understand that some of you might think that I have some brain problems if I am asking a question like this, but I could not find an answer by googling so I want to ask you this question pleas do not flame me

So can I compile and use "Media Player Classic" in ubuntu (using source code) considering there is only windows build available of this software ??

Thank you in advanced

Comment: You are talking about tag, must have written it automatically sry 
All done fixed

Comment: For the vote-to-closers: I think this is very much **ontopic**. Building native C++ applications is really possible on Linux/Ubuntu as per my answer providing an example. See also: [How should we interpret "Development on Ubuntu" in the FAQ?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5744/88802)

Comment: @gertvdijk There was a 13.04 tag on it at first that's why I closed voted. But I told that in a comment and he replied within 5 minutes, and then I removed my comment. I can't remove my close vote, so it will just die in a couple o days.

Comment: Sorry this awkward situation is my fault after I got the answer I have not checked askubuntu I should have replied to gertvdijk and told you the issue Alvar is right that really happened
again I apologize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't build most Windows specifics as it needs all the libraries installed to link to it. However, some basic or cross-platform development can be done using the MinGW compiler. For example Pidgin for Windows can be built on Linux as described [here on their wiki](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/BuildingWinPidgin#CrossCompiling).

This is possible because MinGW provides an optional Win32 runtime for Linux and it's depending on cross-platform tested libraries like GTK.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to?

Use [WINE](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa) instead. It gets most windows programs to run under linux. (The only drawback that it's incapable of handling .NET)